# Can we add custom keys in Tiff file or how to add temperature data in image properties of Tiff file

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimage, tiff

I want to add temperature data of image at selected point. Is there any pre defined property of it or does we can create custom/ private keys in Tiff file to store temperature data of image.

Answer:

Use TIFF Library documentation to create your own custom keys in TIFF file. in documentaiton he mention how to create and use of custom keys.

http://www.libtiff.org/libtiff.html

Comment: Have you looked at what this company did? http://www.compix.com/fileformattif.htm

Comment: Thanks @BitBank. It will give some idea for me. Will check it and let you know status of it.

Comment: @BitBank verified the data of it. No luck..

Comment: Create your own TIFF tags

Comment: can you guide me how to create our own custom tags in Tiff file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @BitBank Please guide me how to create custom key in tiff file. 

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see this page: http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/faq.html

Comment: @BitBank Thanks, But unable to find any solution there. Tried with TIFF library, but unable to add our own custom keys using iOS. Please help me to find solution on this.

Comment: I had assumed you had written your own code to generate the TIFF file. Adding custom tags is simple if you don't depend on generic solutions. I can write the code. Contact me if you're interested (bitbank@pobox.com).

Answer (score 0):

You can't add custom EXIF keys, but you may be able to cheat...

You could look up the available keys and see if any of them are a legitimate match. Or you could add a custom format string to `kCGImagePropertyTIFFImageDescription` to store your data. It could be a snippet of JSON for example.

```
NSMutableDictionary *properties = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *tags = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[properties setObject:@"whatever text you want goes here" forKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyTIFFImageDescription];

[tags setObject:properties forKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyTIFFDictionary];
```

Then save the tags with the image.

The other keys are documented [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImageProperties_Reference/Reference/reference.html).

Comment: If we use this, it will not display as what ever key we provided and waste of it doing, solved the issue by using TIFF library.

Comment: @Madhu please add an answer if you have found a good solution :-)