# How to save multiple Tiff files into a single Tiff file in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, tiff

I am unable to save multiple Tiff files into single tiff file. Please guide me how to handle this issue in objective-c. On my search from all option there is never get much information Tiff using Objective-c or iOS.

I am unable to use custom keys in Tiff file also from iOS. I found Tiff library to add/ create custom tags for Tiff library, but its not working with iOS.

Please help me with these issues...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well I could offer you a workaround if it would help you somehow. You could first convert the multiple tiff files into a pdf and then convert the pdf into a single tiff file. This is the basic logic. Also both methods can be separately found .

Comment: Thanks for information. Will verify and fix issue with your suggestion. Is there any option to create custom keys in TIFF file in iOS?

Comment: Can u check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16880183/can-we-add-custom-keys-in-tiff-file-or-how-to-add-temperature-data-in-image-prop

Comment: there is no answer at provided link. I have one doubt here, i am unable to move all tiff files into single file, If at all if we moves all files into single does it act like GIF file or PDF file. Does the data which we have stored in each tiff file be exist..?


Please help me to find the proper solution to it. Please provide some use full helpful links to resolve my issues.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The challenge in linking TIFF files together is for data which doesn't fit in the tags; the offsets are absolute, not relative and must be relocated for each page. If you created the TIFF file yourself and know which tags you used, it's pretty easy. Merging someone else's TIFF files requires a bit more care.